# Grouping sequence number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below.

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    [Text] varchar(100), 
    [Order] int, 
    [RequiredResult] int
);

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES 
('A',1,1),
('B',2,1),
('C',3,1),
('D',1,2),
('A',2,2),
('B',3,2),
('G',4,2),
('H',1,3),
('B',2,3);
```

I have used `dense_rank`, but the results are not correct.

```
select [Text], [Order], RequiredResult
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [text],[Order]) AS ComputedResult
from @Table;
```

Results:

| Text | Order | RequiredResult | ComputedResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| C | 3 | 1 | 5 |
| D | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| G | 4 | 2 | 7 |
| H | 1 | 3 | 8 |

Please help me to calculate the `RequiredResult` column.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax in the question.

Comment: Your results seem to assume an ordering of the rows.  There is no column in your table that is an obvious ordering column.  How do you know the ordering?

Comment: Does `RequiredResult` show the value that you want to compute? if so your example query is not accurate because it doesn't return the original `RequiredResult` column. Its just not clear what is actually wrong here

Comment: I still don't get what is incorrect, looks like `dense_rank` is doing what it is supposed to do. What are you trying to do, it's completely unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `RequiredResult` column is simple a running sequence that resets after each broken sequence in the `Order` column when you process the records in the order they were inserted.

> This is a typical *Data Island* analysis task, except in this case the islands are the rows that are sequential sets, the boundary is when the numbering resets back to 1.

1. Record the input sequence by adding an `IDENTITY` column to the table variable.
2. Calculate an island identifier

   - Due to the rule about the rows being in sequence based on the `Order` column, we can calculate a unique number for the *Island* by subtracting the `Order` from the *IDENTITY* column, in this case `Id`
3. We can then use `DENSE_RANK()` ordering by the *Island Number*

Putting all that together:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Text] varchar(100), 
    [Order] int, 
    [RequiredResult] int
);

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES 
('A',1,1),
('B',2,1),
('C',3,1),
('D',1,2),
('A',2,2),
('B',3,2),
('G',4,2),
('H',1,3),
('B',2,3);
   
SELECT [Text],[Order]
       , [Id]-[Order] as Island
       , RequiredResult
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [ID]-[ORDER]) AS CalculatedResult
FROM @Table 
ORDER BY [ID]
```

| Text | Order | Island | RequiredResult | CalculatedResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| D | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| G | 4 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| H | 1 | 7 | 3 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 7 | 3 | 3 |

The key here is that we need to record the input sequence so we can us it in the calculation. It doesn't matter what actual numbering value the `Id` column has, only that it is also in sequence. If that number sequence is broken, then you could use the `ROW_NUMER()` function result to calculate the `Island Number` but the specifics on that would depend on the initial query that provides the basic sequential dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an ordering in mind for the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  The only column in your data that has the appropriate ordering is `text`, but your real data might have another column with this information.

Basically, you just want a cumulative sum of the number of `1`s up to each row.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when ord = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by text)
from t
```

Comment: If text column has duplicates then it is not working. @Gordon

Comment: @ANR . . . As the answer explains, you need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.  This uses `text` because that is the only such column available based on the data in the question.

Comment: Is there any way to get required result without using order?

Comment: @ANR how do you imagine that might happen? There is nothing in your data which allows it to be ordered the way you show it...